# SQL Server shows "Invalid object name '#temp'" when working with a temporary table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, temp-tables

I have created a procedure

```
create procedure testProcedure_One 
as
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(4000)

begin
SET @Query = 'SELECT * into #temptest FROM  Table1'

Exec sp_Executesql @query

SELECT * FROM #temptest
drop table #temptest
end
```

When I run the procedure `testProcedure_One` I am getting the error message:

> ```
> Invalid object name '#temp'
> ```

But if I use `##temp means` it's working:

```
create procedure testProcedure_two 
as
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(4000)

begin

SET @Query = 'SELECT * into ##temptest FROM  Table1'


Exec sp_Executesql @query

SELECT * FROM ##temptest
drop table ##temptest
end
```

`testProcedure_two` is working fine

What might be the issue? How can i solve it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Presumably you have following code that SELECTs from #temp, giving you the error?

It's down to scope. ##temp is a global temporary table, available in other sessions. #temp is "local" temporary table, only accessible by the current executing scope. sp_executesql runs under a different scope, and so it will insert the data into #temp, but if you then try to access that table outside of the sp_executesql call, it won't find it.

e.g.
This errors as #Test is created and only visible to, the sp_executesql context:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql N'SELECT 1 AS Field1 INTO #Test'
SELECT * FROM #Test
```

The above works with ##Test as it creates a global temporary table.

This works, as the SELECT is part of the same scope.

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql N'SELECT 1 AS Field1 INTO #Test; SELECT * FROM #Test'
```

My questions would be:

1. Do you really need to use temp tables, can you not find a solution without them using e.g. a subquery?
2. Do you really need to execute sql like this using sp_executesql?

Comment: Thanks.I know it was out of scope but it didn't strike for me that i have to do the select with the same query.

Answer (score 6):

Create the Temporary table by using **CREATE TABLE** and then use **INSERT INTO** to insert the values instead of SELECT INTO.

This rectified the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

for you to execute i think that the #tmp_table should be created first using a ddl statement.

Then you execute your exec and the stored proc you have created in the exec should have the same named `temp table viz.#tmp_table`.